# Is there a way to do a login (Identity or even better a generic one) from an external library in .Net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Problem is that you need to know the user class (TUser) to get the SignInManager from DI and that is unknown for an external component (eg. controller i separate lib)...

Also, is there any official way to check if Identity is added to the middleware chain?

Update - Because of some confusion:

If you develop your own framework containing a backend that uses the Identity for authorisation, is it possbible to write a login controller / view that is conatined in your library and still make it possible for the developer consuming your framework to extend the Identity framework with for example their own User class, DbContext and so on?

My main problem is how to get hold of the SignInManager (from DI) without knowing the underlying generic user class...

Hope this makes things clearer :)

Comment: Identity *is* the generic middleware that allows you to authenticate using various providers. As for the question text - the question is unclear. What problem are you talking about? What external component?

Comment: Identity is far from generic :) you could use windows, cookie or some other total different type of authentication. With external component I'm refering to my own code...

Comment: Redesign your architecture. When you think you need to login from a library, then your design is pretty much flawed. FYI: ASP.NET Core is an **web application** (emphasis on **web**), you don't login "from the library", you login via a http request

Comment: That was the most flawed answer of the year :D how can you even make that conclusion just knowing what i've written?!

Comment: @bang things that are already supported by it. I suspect you misunderstand what Identity is. It has a *provider* model that supports *any* type of authentication as long as you have the appropriate provider. And it *does* support a lot of providers already - the documentation shows you how to configure Windows Authentication, Google, Facebook, local accounts *and* how to create your own provider

Comment: Read the documentation *first* before making assumptions. [Read the introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) which shows how you can use local accounts, how to [configure Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) ...

Comment: how to use [various social providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/) with specific step-by-step instructions for [Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins), [Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins), [Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins),

Comment: short instructions for [other social providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/other-logins) like VK

Comment: Shows how to create your own [storage provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers) with examples for cloud storage

Comment: [Cookies can work independently of ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) if you want. [There are 45 contributed providers in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=owners%3Aaspnet-contrib+title%3AOAuth) including DeviantArt (?!)

Comment: @bang all in all, yes, Identity is the generic mechanism. Yes you can extend it. Yes, I agree with Tseng's comment. And no this is not a well formed question. If you have questions about authentication in ASP.NET Core, ask a *specific* question.

Comment: I just want to know if what I'm trying to do is possible or not. And a No would be find :) I'm I senior developer and I do understand your points of view but I still can't see how it's possible for you to comment on my architecture with so little information. Ask instead of more info if you don't understand... This is not at all what I was asking for and I will stop commenting this twist.

Comment: @bank the answer is not only YES, I already provided links to a lot of existing implementations. It's *your* responsibility to post a good question and provide enough information so others can understand it and answer. Just look at how many downotes this got. It's not me and it's not Tseng. We are the only ones that bothered

Comment: @bank you'll have to be *specific*. *What* do you want to implement? Why would you need a custom User class? Are you confusing *authentication* with *user profiles* perhaps? These are completely separate concerns. They'v always been implemented by different services in ASP.NET

Comment: Allready read a most of your refs, but I have not found an answer to my question, thats why I went to this place... And I still feels that it's a rather simple yes/no question: Can I get hold of the SignInManager (from DI) without knowing the underlying generic user class ? But if I have missed the answer in one of your links, please point me to it :)

Comment: I suggest you read [How Do I Ask A Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center, and [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). I'm the only one that actually bothered to comment up to now. If the question was well written, someone else would have answered

Comment: :D That was low! Read both (long time ago) and I agree I could have given it one or two more minutes, but still can't see why you don't understand it now. It's a one-liner, yes/no question... maybe it's getting personal ;) ?

Comment: This place used to be a very nice and forgiven place. Hope that has not changed...

Answer (score 0):

Found some kind of solution / work around...
You still need to know the user type (but not necessarily at runtime), and then you can get the signInManager from DI doing something like this:

```
        var userType = typeof(ApplicationUser);
        var signInManagerType = typeof(SignInManager<>).MakeGenericType(userType);

        var signInManager = ServiceProvider.GetServices(signInManagerType);
```